# Convert a Chrome extension to a userscript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, userscripts

Is there any way to take a Chrome extension and convert it to a userscript?

I've seen multiple tutorials on converting a userscript to a Chrome extension, but nothing for going the other way.

Comment: If the extension doesn't use any extension API and only uses standard JavaScript, it can be converted into a userscript. Userscripts run in `content` context so only the `"content_scripts"` in the `manifest.json` (if doesn't use extension API) can be converted.